# NullPointer Exception updating table rows with Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, nullpointerexception, null, onitemlongclicklistener

I get NullPointer Exception at line 37 of this code, just where it says

```
fragment_monday.add(((TextView) editText).getText().toString());
```

Here is the full file:

```
package com.example.classorganizer;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

class EditListItemDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

private View editText;

public EditListItemDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_dialog);//here is your xml with EditText and 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons
    View btnOk = findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private List<String> fragment_monday;

public EditListItemDialog(Context context, List<String> fragment_monday) {
    super(context);
    this.fragment_monday = fragment_monday;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    fragment_monday.add(((TextView) editText).getText().toString());//here is your updated(or not updated) text
    dismiss();
}
}
```

I get this error when I click confirm button in Dialog to update the row in the table.
Some object on that line is null but I don't have an idea how to deal with this...
Can anyone help please?

Edit: should I post different code just let me know.

Here comes the logcat:

```
04-20 20:44:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 20:44:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2272): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 20:44:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2272):     at com.example.classorganizer.EditListItemDialog.onClick(EditListItemDialog.java:37)
04-20 20:44:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2272):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-20 20:44:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2272):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-20 20:44:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2272):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-20 20:44:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2272):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-20 20:44:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2272):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-20 20:44:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-20 20:44:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 20:44:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-20 20:44:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-20 20:44:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-20 20:44:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2272):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here I post xml file to show that edit_text is there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

File where I set OnItemLongClickListener:

```
package com.example.classorganizer;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cookbook.data.Constants;
import com.cookbook.data.MyDB;




public class Monday extends ListActivity {



private static final int MyMenu = 0;
MyDB dba;
DiaryAdapter myAdapter;

private class MyDiary{
    public MyDiary(String t, String c){
        title=t;
        content=c;

        ListView list = getListView();
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    new EditListItemDialog(view.getContext()).show();

                return true;       
            }
        });

}

    public String title;
    public String content;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dba = new MyDB(this);
    dba.open();
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_monday);





    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(this);
    this.setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}



private class DiaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<MyDiary> fragment_monday;
    public DiaryAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        fragment_monday = new ArrayList<MyDiary>();
        getdata();


    }

    public void getdata(){
        Cursor c = dba.getdiaries();
        startManagingCursor(c);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String title =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.TITLE_NAME));
                String content =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONTENT_NAME));

                MyDiary temp = new MyDiary(title,content);
                fragment_monday.add(temp);
            } while(c.moveToNext());
        }

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {return fragment_monday.size();}
    public MyDiary getItem(int i) {return fragment_monday.get(i);}
    public long getItemId(int i) {return i;}
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        View v = arg1;
        if ((v == null) || (v.getTag() == null)) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.diaryrow,  null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.mdiary = getItem(arg0);
        holder.mTitle.setText(holder.mdiary.title);


        v.setTag(holder);

        return v;


    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        MyDiary mdiary;
        TextView mTitle;


    }

}




/** Called when the user clicks the Edit button */
public void visitDiary(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Diary.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
/** Called when the user clicks the back button */
public void visitSchedule(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayScheduleScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


}
```

Here is the part of fragment_monday xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                         <ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:longClickable="true"
     >

</ListView>



             </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Most likely because your editText is null. Probably no `EditText` with id `R.id.edit_text` can be found in the layout. But that is just a guess. You need to post the logcat so we can identify the cause.

Comment: Ummm, what if you try `fragment_monday.add((EditText) v).gettext().tostring());`

Comment: And `View editText` would be a `ÈditText` or a `TextView`?

Comment: Post `edit_text_dialog.xml` layout file.

Comment: @algui91 I tried with v instead of editText and crashes on same line.

Comment: @algui91 I am not sure what you mean by saying View editText would be a ÈditText or a TextView

Comment: Because I think you have in your XML a EditText and in the funcion onlick you are casting to TextView

Comment: Try to cast your view to a EditText not a TextView. `fragment_monday.add(((EditText) editText).getText().toString());`

Comment: @KieronPapps same NullPointer Exception at same line when clicking the button...

Comment: Try to debug the program, put a breakpoint at line 37 and watch what variable is null. I would think is `fragment_monday`

Comment: Check on this line for null edittext  editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text)

Comment: Where do you set the fragment? It seems like its in the constructor. Do you have that code? My gut is saying that the fragment is null. It might be worth trying to print a statement if it's still null just to check.

Comment: @KieronPapps check my updated code snipped. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @jk2praj but editText seems to be defined and called properly. There is reference

Comment: You seem to be not passing in `fragment_monday` to the constructor and hence is null when you try to add something to it.

Comment: @KieronPapps any idea how this can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

I am still thinking `fragment_monday` is null, in this snippet:

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                new EditListItemDialog(view.getContext()).show();

            return true;       
        }
    });
```

You are creating the dialog with the constructor `EditListItemDialog(Context context)` But in the onlick he is using `fragment_monday`. Which is not initialized.

Comment: this would mean that I need to update the above code with fragment_monday

Comment: where you set your `OnItemLongClickListener` you need to create the dialog with your constructor `EditListItemDialog(Context context, List<String> fragment_monday)`, not `EditListItemDialog(Context context)`

Comment: This is what I get when I change this code: Multiple markers at this line
 - fragment_monday cannot be resolved to a variable
 - List cannot be resolved to a variable
 - Syntax error on token "context", delete this token
 - Context cannot be resolved to a variable
 - String cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @lisoslaw What do you want to show in the dialog?, All items in the listview or only one of them?

Comment: I want to use dialog to update one row only. Any row

Comment: Yes, I am checking your code to come up with a solution.

Comment: The problem I think is that you are registering a onclick listener (By creating a new MyDiary object) for every row in the listview (in DiaryAdapter). And then in Mydiary you are accesing the Listview again. Maybe I am confused. But I think you should try to register that onclick listener from within your Adapter. And then from there you can access the data of the row. Sorry for my english. I am Spanish.

Comment: @lisoslaw If I understand well what you want to do, The basic idea is that you register the onlick listener from within your baseadapter class. I once wrote in my blog something similar but for a checkBox in every row. The idea is likely the same. My blog is in spanish, but hope the code helps you. http://elbauldelprogramador.com/adapter-personalizado-en-android/

Comment: and by baseadapter class you mean which class? sorry for immature question

Comment: @lisoslaw sorry, my fault, I mean your `DiaryAdapter` that extends `BaseAdapter`

Comment: I moved snipped to DiaryAdapter class that extends BaseAdapter but doing only this doesn't give any other effects, I get NullPointer Exception from EditListItemDialog file where the onClick method is.

Comment: @lisoslaw Could you send me your project and I will try it?